# Is there a O(1) way to remove nil values from a Swift collection?

Tags: arrays, swift, algorithm

I was thinking of a custom `Collection`, something like:

```
for i in [1, 2, nil].nilValuesRemoved() {
     print(i)
}
```

would print:

```
1
2
```

The actual `.nilValuesRemoved()` call would be `O(1)`, kind of the same way `.reverse()` works. Would that be possible?

Comment: Not possible for collection type.

Comment: `lazy.compactMap` can *ignore* the values. If there are `k` `nil` values, you will still have to iterate `O(n)` times, not `O(n-k)` times.

Comment: What is the rationale of such a request ? Whatever the data structure, you have to specify which elements are nil, and that takes O(k) for k elements. Whatever your algorithm does, it is at least O(n) and that exceeds O(k). So a nilValuesRemoved that takes O(k) is good enough. Don't consider that O(1) means "fast" and O(k) "slow".

Comment: @YvesDaoust Iterating the list once is faster than iterating it twice, and avoiding allocating memory to copy the array can be even more important. We don't have nearly as good vocabulary in CS to discuss memory churn as we do complexity analysis (even though memory churn is often just as important or more in practice), but "O(1)" is still a reasonable way to describe what is being looked for here.

Comment: @RobNapier: I repeat, this O(1) would be absorbed in another O(k) and this requirement might very well be counter-productive. A very good example is lazy compaction, which can have a very high cost.

Comment: @RobNapier: if you use the asymptotic notation, accept the rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a lazy compactMap:

```
for i in ([1, 2, nil].lazy.compactMap{$0}) {
     print(i)
}
```

This creates a `LazyMapSequence` in O(1).

`.lazy` is a general solution to this problem, making the application O(1) and avoiding an intermediate allocation, at the cost of making multiple iterations more expensive.

---

It's possible that the title of this question will confuse some readers, though the question is quite clear. To be explicit: Actually iterating over the result will still be O(n), just as iterating over the result of `.reverse()` is O(n) even though the call to `.reverse()` is O(1).

Comment: While I agree in what you stated –lazy compactMap is an O(1) operation– the whole code snippet is O(n) and nothing can be done to have a "true" O(n) nil removal. The whole point of `lazy` is to defer the computation to some later point, and in the code you write the later point is at the same line, which defeats the whole point of lazy. I just want to emphasis that no, there is not a O(1) way to remove nil values from an array, that is not true. However that is true that lazy can saves computations if the collection is not fully iterated, and it can also reduce memory footprint.

Comment: The question was pretty clear, however, that the asker understood this. "The actual .nilValuesRemoved() call would be O(1)." The asker did not request that the `for` loop be O(1). While possibly helpful information for other readers, I do not believe the asker was confused on this point.

Comment: Sure, the actual confusion is with the post title which doesn't express the same issue as the body.